# What is an efficient way to store file paths in C?

Tags: c, string, performance, optimization

I have written a program that calculates a folders total disk usage by using multiple threads.

What’s the best way to store file paths in C in my case? The file path is only used once to open the file/folder to get its size or iterate over the files it contains. And the path is also needed to build new paths by concatenating the files found with the path.

Right now I just strcpy the file path and filename together to an allocated memory location.

Example:

```
char *build_path(char *previous_path, char *file_name)
{
   char *new_path = calloc(1, (strlen(previous_path) + strlen(file_name) + strlen(”/”) + 1) * sizeof(char));

   strcpy(new_path, previous_path);
   strcat(new_path, ”/”);
   strcat(new_path, file_name);

   // I know I could use snprintf, but it gave me a slower runtime.

   return new_path;
}
```

It feels like I’m duplicating strings and that this could be done more efficiently, like with a trie for example. So that I dont need to duplicate the roots multiple times over.

I’m just looking for the most time efficient method, memory usage is not important.

Comment: You’re right, I used the wrong functions for my example. I am using strcat in my program though. @Gerhardh

Comment: You can use `edit` button below your question to fix that.

Comment: If you end up doing a system call to retrieve file size from disk, any performance gained by not copying some short strings are probably not even measurable.

Comment: One obvious performance improvement is to compute string lengths only once. Now, both `strcat` calls end up iterating over the `new_path` until the null terminator.

Comment: you're falling into the [Shlemiel the painter’s algorithm](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/) by finding string length with `strlen` then do it again in the next 3 `str*()` functions. Avoid the raw C string and always store string length properly like any proper string type in non-C languages, such as `std::string` in C++

Comment: Do you have a *measurable* performance problem?

Comment: Great suggestions, thanks for the insight! That will help for sure!

Comment: Not having performance problems per se.. Just trying to learn how to maximise my program to the extremes. @tadman

Comment: It's often the case that the naive approach, as you've done here, is good enough for the task at hand. If you optimize it now, you may end up with a complex, but non-optimal approach that is going to be difficult to refactor into something better, you'll have hit a local maximum. I'd leave it like this until you get into a bind, like you're running this on a tree with millions of files, and you can get good test results.

Comment: You can store this in a tree hierarchy. You only need to build path when required. Prebuilding all the path can be quite expensive both in space (memory usage) and time (CPU). Besides, you can align strings on a 16-bytes boundary and allocate block of a multiple of 16-bytes too. Then you can use 128-bit SIMD instructions to speed up string operations. Additionally, storing the size of the string can help to avoid many strlen operations. C strings are not efficient because of that. Using `strlen(”/”)` that will always be 1 is clearly not a good idea... Not to mention `sizeof(char)` is always 1.

Comment: By the way, you can try to build string directly in the stack if possible so to avoid an expensive allocation. On most platforms, paths have a limited size by default (eg. 256 bytes) though it has been extended. An alternative is to allocate paths only when they are huge (eg. > 256) so the cost of the allocation can become small compared to the computation of the string

Comment: Instead of building absolute or relative paths (how many levels deep), then having the OS visit and re-visit and re-visit every segment to locate each "leaf" file (for statistics), consider using `chdir()` yourself so that the program visits every directory and all files are and subdirectories are _right there_... For directories full of files, this should be faster that staying anchored to one location and doing it all "at arm's length"... Clever use of recursion would mean you'd only need one string buffer for the whole program...